# Error while opening a new pgAdmin 4 window

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have just started using pgAdmin 4 PostgreSQL and when I am running it I receive this alert:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50582: getsockopt: connection refused
```

How to deal with it? I am an absolute beginner, so please explain thorougly.

Comment: Is there a transparent proxy on your network? Does the pgAdmin 4 work if you disconnect it form the network (it should)?

Comment: It looks like pgAdmin is trying to connect to something running on port 50582 on your local machine and getting "connection refused". Have you confirmed that postgres is listening on that port on your local machine? If so, is your firewall allowing connections on that port?

Basically, pgAdmin is a client and is trying to connect to that IP:port. It looks like the server isn't running locally or the server wasn't able to listen on the port so the client can connect.

Comment: I suspect it is PGadmin ver 3.0 and its just try to start a browser tab/window. Are you on Windows? Have you got anything that might block 127.0.0.1:50582 ?